# OS X Lion wakeup password dialog ignores keyboard input

Tags: macos, mac, osx-lion

MBP Late 2007
Latest Lion.

I'm stuck in the situation when my notebook wakes from the keyboard just fine, but the password entry dialog ignores any keyboard input. It reacts on mouse clicks.

Is there a way to fix this somehow without forcing reboot?

This is not the first time this happens. I suspect that it is related to ad-hoc wifi being enabled when the MBP goes to sleep...

Answer (score 1):

I have this problem since Lion update as well, in my case it is related to Mail asking for keychain password at wake up/network re-hooking. Basically same SecurityAgent dialog panel failure. No solution but reboot so far.

Answer (score 0):

I’ve had this happen to me intermittently since upgrading to Lion, too. In my case, dismissing the password entry (by clicking the ‘X’), then calling it up again helped.

Comment: Does not work for me :(